# Buscar ID em um select em PHP

Tags: php, select

```
<select class="form-control" name="cliente">
    <?php if ($clientes) {
        foreach($clientes as $ind => $valor) {
     ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $valor->nome ?>"><?php echo $valor->nome ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

Gostaria de entender esse código, tudo indica que ele faz um select e traz a lista para realizar um cadastro.

Comment: O que o código a cima faz é verificar se existe algum valor na variavel $clientes e caso exista ele printa o nome dos clientes em um select. Criando um select de nomes de clientes!

Comment: Este código está criando as opções de um dropdow(Select) porém sem saber todo o escopo da aplicação fica dificil saber qual o proposito do uso disso. Aliás você deveria saber de onde vem isso...

Comment: essa validação if ($clientes) não é muito boa. deixa brecha para erros. Como por exemplo: $clientes = [array()]; passaria na sua validação e geraria o seguinte erro em seu foreach: "NOTICE Trying to get property of non-object on line number 7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=>` é utilizado para associar chave e valor em um vetor.

`->` é utilizado para acessar um método ou propriedade de um objeto.

```
<select class="form-control" name="cliente">
<?php 
   if ($clientes) {   //Se houver algum cliente ele entra no IF
      foreach($clientes as $ind => $valor) { //Para cada cliente ele criará uma opção
         ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $valor->nome ?>"> <!--Seta o valor da opção com propriedade nome do objeto valor. -->
               <?php echo $valor->nome ?> <!--Exibe a propriedade nome do objeto valor.-->
            </option>
         <?php 
      } 
   } 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<select class="form-control" name="cliente">
....
</select>
```

Estas linhas são a abertura e fechamento da tag HTML para criar um objeto de seleção (combo box ou select) na página HTML, e não para realizar um select em um banco de dados. Provavelmente este select já foi realizado em um momento anterior do código, não mostrado em seu exemplo.

```
<?php if ($clientes) {
    foreach($clientes as $ind => $valor) {
 ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $valor->nome ?>"><?php echo $valor->nome ?></option>
<?php } } ?>
```

Nesta porção de código o objeto combo box é populado com as opções. Na linha com o `if` é testado se a variável $clientes possui um valor verdadeiro, neste caso, se ela é o "resultado" da pesquisa em banco, se for nula será considerada falsa e não entra no if, caso contrário, provavelmente por quê possui valores de retorno, entra.

No bloco do `foreach` cada registro do resultado da consulta é percorrido e o índice colocado em `$ind` e o registro em `$valor`. A linha que inicia com a tag  monta a opção de escolha que será mostrada no objeto combo box.